# 'TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'' within if clause. in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, matplotlib, max

Here, from a large data file split into different rows with the same 4th column, I'm trying to plot a line, with only the highest 10% of entries from each row from the 3rd column:

My code is as follows:

```
M1 = max(str(int(row1[i][2]))) #maximum value from row1, 3rd column
M2 = max(str(int(row2[j][2])))

if row1[i][2] >= M1*(0.1):
   plt.plot....
```

this gives me the error:

```
    if row1[i][2] >= M1*float(0.1):
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

my rows look like this (each row on separate line):

```
[[1, -1, 10, 0]]
[[2, 1, 20, 5]]
[[3, 2, 15, 10], [4, 2, 50, 10], [5, 2, 90, 10]]
[[6, 3, 15, 11]]
[[7, 4, 50, 11]]
[[8, 5, 90, 11]]
[[9, 6, 13, 14]]
[[10, 7, 50, 14]]
[[11, 8, 70, 14], [12, 8, 95, 14], [13, 8, 75, 14]].....
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to get the `max` of? When it's a `str`, you're getting the largest digit, without a `str` conversion, you have a single value, so there is nothing to take the `max` of. Really, what is the value and type of the data at `row1[i][2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `str(int())` from `max(str(int(row1[i][2])))`. You can't multipy anything by a `string` neither can you convert a `list` to `int`.

Comment: this then gives me the error     `M1 = max(int(row1[i][2]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: how does the row look like? is it a list? a comma separated string? what exactly?

Comment: an example of a row is `[[3, 2, 15, 10], [4, 2, 50, 10], [5, 2, 90, 10]]`

Comment: okay so you need to declare `M1` simply as `M1 = max(row1[i])`. this will output: `15`, `50` and `90`. it this the desired output?

Comment: Sorry to come back so late, but I've now got a problem with this answer... As the data file goes on, the 3rd column is not always the largest number. So how would I extract the max of the 3rd column (from each row1) only?